# All Sufficiently Large Squares, Represented as Sum of Two Semiprimes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, square-numbers, semiprimes

Define a semiprime to be the product of two (not necessarily distinct) primes, $p_iq_i$.

**Conjecture:** All squares $\ge 4^2$ are representable as the sum of two distinct semiprimes.

---

Case 1: Squares of the form $4n^2$, $n \ge 2$.

Suppose $4n^2=p_1q_1+p_2q_2$.  Allowing $p_1=p_2=2$ simplifies the relation to $2n^2=\left( q_1+q_2 \right)$.  The LHS of the equation is an even number, and the RHS is a sum of two primes, which is equivalent to a weaker version of the Goldbach conjecture.

Case 2: Squares of the form $\left( 2n+1\right)^2$, $n \ge2.$

This is related to a theorem proposed by Meng.  Meng proved that every sufficiently large odd integer is representable as the sum of three semiprimes.  I am however only interested in the case of odd squares, and whether or not two semiprimes will suffice.

---

My question is whether or not this conjecture can be proven without assuming Goldbach's conjecture.  I have checked squares up to $1519^2 \approx 10^{6.3}$ without finding any counterexamples.  I am going to run a few more tests, hopefully up to $10^{10}$.  In the meantime, does anyone have any input?

Comment: I just discovered a stronger conjecture that every sufficiently large *integer* is the sum of two semiprimes.  It is apparently suspected to be true.  http://oeis.org/A072966

Comment: I can't help but see the irony in me mulling over this problem. (I'm completely unrelated to the Meng mentioned in Case 2, just for the record)

Comment: I add MathSciNet data about Meng's paper.

MR2163905 (2006d:11120)
Meng, Xianmeng(PRC-SUF)
On sums of three integers with a fixed number of prime factors. (English summary) 
J. Number Theory 114 (2005), no. 1, 37–65.